# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate occasionally returns null after updating document

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO to receive events. I execute the following code to update a Goal with a new participant. Most of the time this works well, however, sometimes the function returns a null goal **even though the document was successfully updated**.

```js
  socket.on('joinGroup', function(goalID, userName) {
        if (goalID == null || userName == null) {
            return socket.error("Missing some required field")
        }
        Goal.findOneAndUpdate({_id: goalID, 'participants.userID': {$ne : socket.uid}, 'participants.userName': {$ne : userName}}, {$push: {participants: {userID: socket.uid, userName: userName, streak: 0}}}, {new: true},  (err, goal) => {
                if (err) {
                    return socket.error(error)
                } else {
                    if (goal == null) {
                        //Means something is wrong, don't send
                        console.log("Goal is null")
                        return socket.emit('customError', "Unable to join goal. Please try again.")
                    }
                    else {
                        sendMessage(socket.uid, userName + " joined the goal.", goalID, 'joined', userName, true)
                        return socket.emit('goals', {goals: [goal]})    
                    }
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                return console.log(error);
            });;
    });
```

Does anyone have any idea why goal == null ever occurs even after the document successfully updates?

Comment: Most probably it returns `null` because the query does not match any document. Are you sure that `goalID` and `socket.uid` are correct?

Comment: is `_id`  a obejctId mongoose default?

Comment: Yes, _id is objectID mongoose default (it is generated by mongoose). I might spend some more time checking if the query actually is meant to return null in those occasions and something else is wrong if the code looks right.